# Libgdx how to set textfield based on inputs from keyboard?

Tags: libgdx

Just started to use libgdx recently and i want to check how can i get the input from my keyboard to be displayed on the textfield ?

Thanks.

Comment: You will have to be more specific.  What have you tried?  Which Libgdx APIs are you using?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. i have tried using Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.ANY_KEY) to detect any keys and then trying to set the textfield using setText() method. Do i require a listener for my textfield ?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/InputOnscreen check this link out for documentation on OnscreenKeyBoard

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the keyboard, then that link from Kumar will do, if you are trying to get Text to be displayed, then you need to grab the input from the Keyboard with an InputProcessor [LibGDX InputProcessor](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html)

However, to get input from the keyboard and still have input to any other items on your screen, you need to combine that with an InputMultiplexer [LibGDX InputMultiPlexer](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputMultiplexer.html), which can handle multipe InputProcessors

For example, if you have a Stage that you want to handle input, and you want the Keyboard to popout every so often for text input, somewhere in your Create(), you can create a new InputProcessor for your keyboard..

```
keyboardProcessor = new InputProcessor() {

        @Override
        public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //dLog("This is the new processor");
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //dLog("This is the new processor");
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //dLog("This is the new processor");
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //dLog("This is the new processor");
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //dLog("This is the new processor");
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //dLog("This is the new processor");
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
            if(newChatMessage == null){
                return false;
            }

            if((int) character == 10  || (int) character == 13){
                dLog("sending in keyTyped");
                sendChatMessage();
                return false;
            }

            final String originalChatMessage = newChatMessage;

            String tempChatMessage = null;
        //  dLog("q1");
            if((int)character == 8){
        //      dLog("q2");
                if(originalChatMessage.length() > 0 ){
                    tempChatMessage = originalChatMessage.substring(0, originalChatMessage.length() - 1);
                } else {
                    tempChatMessage = "";
                    Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            Assets.soundDoubleBuzzer.play();
                        }

                    });
                }
            } else {
                if(originalChatMessage.length() >= 14){
                    tempChatMessage = originalChatMessage;
                    //dLog("q3");
                    Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Assets.soundDoubleBuzzer.play();
                        }

                    });
                } else {
                    tempChatMessage = originalChatMessage + character;
                }
            }
        //  dLog("q4");
            final String realTemp = tempChatMessage;
        //  dLog("q5");
        //  dLog("user pressed character:" + (int)(character));
        //  dLog("current message is :" + realTemp);
            Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    lblChat.setText(realTemp);
                    newChatMessage = realTemp;
                }

            });

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //dLog("This is the new processor");
            return false;
        }
    };
```

The part to pay attention for filling in your TextField is in the KeyTyped() event.  Each time a character is typed, it will call that method

Then, you add the two InputProcessors to the MultiPlexer  and then set the Gdx.input to the multiPlexer.  (the Stage also implements an InputProcessor...)

```
private InputMultiplexer multiPlexer;
multiPlexer.addProcessor(keyboardProcessor);
    multiPlexer.addProcessor(stage);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiPlexer);
```

This allows both processors to function at the same time... the first one in to the multiplexer gets first shot at handling the input... if it returns false, and the other inputProcessor can handle it, then it will get passed on... otherwise it is ignored..

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I am not trying to use a OnScreenKeyBoard, it is more of using the keyboard of your laptop/ pc  to key into my program. So e.g i want to capture the letter A from keyboard. I understand the letter A = Key.A. Then I want to update my textfield to display "A". Everytime a new letter/key is pressed the textfield will be updated and display the letter.  On a side note, which do you recommend I use, Label or TextField ?

Comment: The input method will work for either one.  As you can see in my example, I add a character to the String newChatMessage (after seeing that it isn't too long, is a valid character... etc)  For display, personal choice on the TextField or Label, as it depends on what functionality you want to have... the TextField definitely has some more options to play with!

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, but i realised my textfield is not updated. Do i have to set a listener for the textfield ? What I am doing now is using textfield1.setText(word);

Comment: An example of my code for setting the textfield upon a button is clicked. 

`code` 
button1 =  new TextButton("A" , skin);
button1.addListener(new ChangeListener(){
@Override
    public void changed(ChangeEvent arg0, Actor arg1) {
     textfield1.setText("" + button1.getText()); 
    }});

Answer (score 1):

```
private String txtVal;

TextField textField= new TextField("textField Vallue", skin);

        textField.setTextFieldListener(new TextFieldListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(TextField textField, char key) {
                    txtVal= textField.getText();
            }
        });

 System.out.println(txtVal);
```