# how to read data in a textfield

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a textfield but I don't know how to save the input. I'm using libgdx's scene2d.

```
txtUsername = new TextField("", mSkin);
     txtUsername.setMessageText("test");
     txtUsername.setPosition(30, 30);   
     mStage.addActor(txtUsername);
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18928295/2777098

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the text you can use `txfUsername.getText();`
when you say save if you mean in a variable use `String yourStringVariable = txfUsername.getText();`I think that saving is basic :), look this similar code : [Cannot show user input with a textfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26661740/libgdx-cant-getting-user-input-with-a-textfield/26662594#26662594)   I hope I understood your question